# How to use order block tops and bottoms to define any rule?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, indicator, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to plot engulf candles on order blocks. But can't use bull_top, bull_btm, bear_top, bear_btm to define engulfing limits. Error message is:

Cannot call 'operator >' with argument 'expr1'='bear_btm'. An argument of 'float[]' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.

How can I use order block tops and bottoms?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Order Block Detector with Engulfs"
, overlay = true
, max_boxes_count = 500
, max_labels_count = 500
, max_lines_count = 500)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Settings

import ArincAkkin/arincLibrary/4 as ari
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
length = input.int(5, 'Volume Pivot Length'
, minval = 1)

bull_ext_last = input.int(3, 'Bullish OB '
, minval = 1
, inline = 'bull')

bg_bull_css = input.color(color.new(#169400, 80), ''
, inline = 'bull')

bull_css = input.color(#169400, ''
, inline = 'bull')

bull_avg_css = input.color(color.new(#9598a1, 37), ''
, inline = 'bull')

bear_ext_last = input.int(3, 'Bearish OB'
, minval = 1
, inline = 'bear')

bg_bear_css = input.color(color.new(#ff1100, 80), ''
, inline = 'bear')

bear_css = input.color(#ff1100, ''
, inline = 'bear')

bear_avg_css = input.color(color.new(#9598a1, 37), ''
, inline = 'bear')

line_style = input.string('⎯⎯⎯', 'Average Line Style'
, options = \['⎯⎯⎯', '----', '····'\])

line_width = input.int(1, 'Average Line Width'
, minval = 1)

mitigation = input.string('Wick', 'Mitigation Methods'
, options = \['Wick', 'Close'\])

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Line Style function
get_line_style(style) =\>
out = switch style
'⎯⎯⎯'  =\> line.style_solid
'----' =\> line.style_dashed
'····' =\> line.style_dotted

//Function to get order block coordinates
get_coordinates(condition, top, btm, ob_val)=\>
var ob_top  = array.new_float(0)
var ob_btm  = array.new_float(0)
var ob_avg  = array.new_float(0)
var ob_left = array.new_int(0)

    float ob = na

    //Append coordinates to arrays
if condition
    avg = math.avg(top, btm)
    
    array.unshift(ob_top, top)
    array.unshift(ob_btm, btm)
    array.unshift(ob_avg, avg)
    array.unshift(ob_left, time[length])
    
    ob := ob_val

[ob_top, ob_btm, ob_avg, ob_left, ob]

//Function to remove mitigated order blocks from coordinate arrays
remove_mitigated(ob_top, ob_btm, ob_left, ob_avg, target, bull)=\>
mitigated = false
target_array = bull ? ob_btm : ob_top

for element in target_array
    idx = array.indexof(target_array, element)
    
    if (bull ? target < element : target > element)
        mitigated := true

        array.remove(ob_top, idx)
        array.remove(ob_btm, idx)
        array.remove(ob_avg, idx)
        array.remove(ob_left, idx)

mitigated

//Function to set order blocks
set_order_blocks(ob_top, ob_btm, ob_left, ob_avg, ext_last, bg_css, border_css, lvl_css)=\>
var ob_box = array.new_box(0)
var ob_lvl = array.new_line(0)

//Fill arrays with boxes/lines
if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to ext_last-1
        array.unshift(ob_box, box.new(na,na,na,na
          , xloc = xloc.bar_time
          , extend= extend.right
          , bgcolor = bg_css
          , border_color = color.new(border_css, 70)))

        array.unshift(ob_lvl, line.new(na,na,na,na
          , xloc = xloc.bar_time
          , extend = extend.right
          , color = lvl_css
          , style = get_line_style(line_style)
          , width = line_width))

//Set order blocks
if barstate.islast
    if array.size(ob_top) > 0
        for i = 0 to math.min(ext_last-1, array.size(ob_top)-1)
            get_box = array.get(ob_box, i)
            get_lvl = array.get(ob_lvl, i)

            box.set_lefttop(get_box, array.get(ob_left, i), array.get(ob_top, i))
            box.set_rightbottom(get_box, array.get(ob_left, i), array.get(ob_btm, i))

            line.set_xy1(get_lvl, array.get(ob_left, i), array.get(ob_avg, i))
            line.set_xy2(get_lvl, array.get(ob_left, i)+1, array.get(ob_avg, i))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Global elements
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var os = 0
var target_bull = 0.
var target_bear = 0.

n = bar_index
upper = ta.highest(length)
lower = ta.lowest(length)

if mitigation == 'Close'
target_bull := ta.lowest(close, length)
target_bear := ta.highest(close, length)
else
target_bull := lower
target_bear := upper

os := high\[length\] \> upper ? 0 : low\[length\] \< lower ? 1 : os\[1\]

phv = ta.pivothigh(volume, length, length)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Get bullish/bearish order blocks coordinates
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
\[bull_top
, bull_btm
, bull_avg
, bull_left
, bull_ob\] = get_coordinates(phv and os == 1, hl2\[length\], low\[length\], low\[length\])

\[bear_top
, bear_btm
, bear_avg
, bear_left
, bear_ob\] = get_coordinates(phv and os == 0, high\[length\], hl2\[length\], high\ [length\])

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Remove mitigated order blocks
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
mitigated_bull = remove_mitigated(bull_top
, bull_btm
, bull_left
, bull_avg
, target_bull
, true)

mitigated_bear = remove_mitigated(bear_top
, bear_btm
, bear_left
, bear_avg
, target_bear
, false)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Display order blocks
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Set bullish order blocks
set_order_blocks(bull_top
, bull_btm
, bull_left
, bull_avg
, bull_ext_last
, bg_bull_css
, bull_css
, bull_avg_css)

//Set bearish order blocks
set_order_blocks(bear_top
, bear_btm
, bear_left
, bear_avg
, bear_ext_last
, bg_bear_css
, bear_css
, bear_avg_css)

//Show detected order blocks
plot(bull_ob, 'Bull OB', bull_css, 2, plot.style_linebr
, offset = -length
, display = display.none)

plot(bear_ob, 'Bear OB', bear_css, 2, plot.style_linebr
, offset = -length
, display = display.none)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

bull_eng=low\<(bull_top) and close\>(bull_btm) and ari.engulfBull()
bear_eng=high\>(bear_btm) and close\<(bear_top) and ari.engulfBear()

plotshape( bull_eng  , title="Buy", text="Be", location=location.belowbar,                  style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(34, 129, 50), textcolor=color.white )
plotshape( bear_eng  , title="Sell", text="Se", location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(255, 122, 5), textcolor=color.rgb(0, 0, 0) )

//Alerts
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
alertcondition(bull_ob, 'Bullish OB Formed', 'Bullish order block detected')

alertcondition(bear_ob, 'Bearish OB Formed', 'bearish order block detected')

alertcondition(mitigated_bull, 'Bullish OB Mitigated', 'Bullish order block mitigated')

alertcondition(mitigated_bear, 'Bearish OB Mitigated', 'bearish order block mitigated')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}` `
```